# Clickable images on radio buttons with jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I'm trying to add images for my answers-options and make them clickable instead of having the choices on a questionnaire, but I'm really stuck.

I don't know if I have to create CSS classes for the buttons and then make them *hide*. But anyway, maybe my head is full of things and can't see a quick solution.

Can anyone help me with this?

I would really appreciate it.

Here's some of my code.

Thanks for the support, hope all you have a wonderful year!!

```
 (function() {

  var questions = [{
    question: "¿En qué estado tienes tu idea de negocio?",
    choices: ["Idea", "Boceto", "Maduración"],
  }, {
    question: "Almacenamiento de datos",
    choices: ["Internet","App","No lo sé"],
  }, {
    question: "Calidad de tu App",
    choices: ["Alta", "Media", "Baja", "No lo sé"],
  }, {
    question: "¿Para qué dispositivo quieres desarrollarlo?",
    choices: ["Android", "iOS", "Android/iOS"],
  }, {
    question: "Interfaz de tu App",
    choices: ["Sencilla", "Llamativa", "Animada"],
  }, {
    question: "Beneficio extra de tu App",
    choices: ["Publicidad", "App de pago", "Compras en la App", "No lo sé"],
  }, {
    question: "Sistema de ingreso a tu App",
    choices: ["Redes Sociales", "E-mail", "Ninguna", "No lo sé"],
  }, {
    question: "Intregraciones",
    choices: ["Sí", "No", "No lo sé"],
  }, {
    question: "Configuración perfil de usuario",
    choices: ["Sí", "No", "No lo sé"],
  }, {
    question: "Panel de administración",
    choices: ["Sí", "No", "No lo sé"],
  }, {
    question: "¿Quieres que tu app genere reportes?",
    choices: ["Sí", "No", "No lo sé"],
  }, {
    question: "¿Quieres hacerla multilenguaje?",
    choices: ["1 idioma", "2 idiomas", "Multilenguajes"],
  }];

  var questionCounter = 0; //Tracks question number
  var selections = []; //Array containing user choices
  var quiz = $('#quiz'); //Quiz div object

  // Display initial question
  displayNext();

  // Click handler for the 'next' button
  $('#next').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Suspend click listener during fade animation
    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {        
      return false;
    }
    choose();

    // If no user selection, progress is stopped
    if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
      alert('Por favor selecciona una opción');
    } else {
      questionCounter++;
      displayNext();
    }
  });

  // Click handler for the 'prev' button
  $('#prev').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    choose();
    questionCounter--;
    displayNext();
  });

  // Click handler for the 'Start Over' button
  $('#start').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    questionCounter = 0;
    selections = [];
    displayNext();
    $('#start').hide();
  });

  // Animates buttons on hover
  $('.button').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
  $('.button').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });


  // Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and 
  // the answer selections
  function createQuestionElement(index) {
    var qElement = $('<div>', {
      id: 'question'
    });

    var image=$('<div>',{'id':'imagelogo'});

    var header = $('<h5>' + (index + 1) + '/12</h5>').addClass('contador');
    qElement.append(header).append(image);


    var question = $('<p>').append(questions[index].question);
    qElement.append(question);

    var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
    qElement.append(radioButtons);

    return qElement;
  }

  // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
  function createRadios(index) {
    var radioList = $('<ul>');
    var item;
    var input = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
      item = $('<li>');
      input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
      input += questions[index].choices[i];
      item.append(input);
      radioList.append(item);
    }
    return radioList;
  }

  // Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
  function choose() {
    selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
  }

  // Displays next requested element
  function displayNext() {
    quiz.fadeOut(function() {
      $('#question').remove();

      if(questionCounter < questions.length){
        var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
        quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
        if (!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
          $('input[value='+selections[questionCounter]+']').prop('checked', true);
        }

        // Controls display of 'prev' button
        if(questionCounter === 1){
          $('#prev').show();
        } else if(questionCounter === 0){

          $('#prev').hide();
          $('#next').show();
        }
      }else {
        var scoreElem = displayScore();
        quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
        $('#next').hide();
        $('#prev').hide();
        $('#start').show();
      }
    });
  }

  // Computes score and returns a paragraph element to be displayed
  function displayScore() {
    var score = $('<p>',{id: 'question'});

    var numCorrect = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
      if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
        numCorrect++;
      }
    }

    score.append('<strong>¡A punto de aterrizar!</strong>' + '<br>' + 'En unos minutos nuestro equipo especializado' +
                 ' se contactará contigo');
    return score;
  }
})();
```

Here's my HTML code.

```
<!-- Page Content -->
    <section class="content-section-a spacing idea">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-12">
      <div class="container">
        <center>
        <h3 class="color" id="left"><strong> Hola (Nombre y Apellido) </strong> <br> <span id="left"> Calculemos tu App </span> </h3>
        </center>
        <br>
      </div> 
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-12">
        <div class="container">
          <div id='quiz'></div>
          <div class='button' id='next'><a href='#'>Siguiente</a></div>
          <div class='button' id='prev'><a href='#'>Anterior</a></div>
          <div class='button' id='start'> <a href='#'>Comenzar nuevamente</a></div>
          <!-- <button class='' id='next'> Siguiente </a></button>
          <button class='' id='prev'> Anterior </a></button>
          <button class='' id='start'> Comenzar nuevamente </a></button> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <!--End of Page Content-->
```

Comment: That is the full script without the HTML. Please read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve);

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've already added. No need to gave me a -1